# form two arrays in a for loop checking for ignition state change condition

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, flags

I need a logic which checks for ignition state change and if the ignition is on push that index into start array and if state then changes to off push into stop array so that I can consider one start array index to stop array index as one trip. I had a logic but this pushes all the start values and all the stop values I only need state change index

```
$isIgniOn = false;  $startArray = array(); $stopArray = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($reportData); $i++) {

        if ($reportData[$i]['ignition_status'] == 1) {
            $startArray[] = $i;
            $isIgniOn = true;

        } else {
            if ($isIgniOn) {
                $isIgniOn = false;
                $stopArray[] = $i;
            } else {
                $startArray[] = $i;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are not actually checking to see if the state has changed and need to add some extra logic in your program:

```
$isIgniOn = false;  $startArray = array(); $stopArray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($reportData); $i++) {

    if ($reportData[$i]['ignition_status'] == 1 && !$isIgniOn) {
        $startArray[] = $i;
        $isIgniOn = true;

    } elseif ($reportData[$i]['ignition_status'] == 0 && $isIgniOn) {
       {
            $isIgniOn = false;
            $stopArray[] = $i;
        }

    }

}
```